# Nginx proxy pass, Showing Directory but Not serving static files in the directory

Tags: nginx

i have the this problem
Now I am on server 1(nginx) working on port 80.
when I type this link in url it should navigate to my server 2(Apapche) which runs on port 8080.
It is working fine. That is, it is getting navigated and displaying the contents of the directory(demo_static_file) but not displaying the file ie; a1.txt

the down is my nginx config.

```
  location /a1.txt {
   proxy_pass http://35.10.28.10:8080/demo_static_file;
  }
```

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://35.10.28.10:8080/demo_static_file$uri;`

Comment: @RichardSmith No it also not working it shows "Not Found"
The requested URL /demo_static_file/a1.txt/ was not found on this server.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried what you suggested. Its not showing the static file content in browser. but its work fine with the CURL command.
It shows the static file content with curl --raw http://<ip>/dir/a1.txt

Comment: Try clearing your browser’s cache